# send chat marker in xmpp group chat

Tags: javascript, xmpp

I'm creating chat app using xmpp and angular 7

I want the chat marker to show up when a user send a message to another user 
it works if i send a message in one to one chat 
but it doesn't work if it's a group chat

what should i change in my code ?

```
 sendChatMarker(to: string, messageId: string, messagetype: string, marker: string, connection) {
//create message stanza for the chat marker

  let chatMarker = $msg({
    to: to,
    from: connection.jid,
    id: generateUUIDv4(),
  })
    .c(marker, {
      xmlns: this.xmppNamespacesService.chatMarkerNS,
      id: messageId
    })
    .up()
    .c("store", {
      xmlns: this.xmppNamespacesService.messageProcessingHintsNS
    }); //to archive chat markers

  //send the chat marker
  connection.send(chatMarker.tree());
  console.log(marker + " chat Marker is sent.", chatMarker.tree());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you receive a group chat message, you receive this stanza:

```
<message
    from='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit/thirdwitch'
    id='hysf1v37'
    to='crone1@shakespeare.lit/desktop'
    type='groupchat'>
  <body>Harpier cries: 'tis time, 'tis time.</body>
</message>
```

As you can see the type of this message is 'groupchat'. So what you have to do, is look for this type, and when you receive it show the marker.

If you need further details here's the XEP where I found it.
https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#message
The stanza is under section 7.4.